# Minimal polynomial of $T(A) = A^\top - A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, minimal-polynomials, transpose

As said in the title , I need to find the minimal polynomial of the linear transformation
$$T(A)=A^\top-A.$$
The matrices are $M_n(\mathbb{C})$. I've figured out that $T^2 = 2A - 2A^t$ , so a polynomial $p(t) = t^2 + 2t$ works so $p(T) = 0$. Now $p(t)$ breaks to $t(t+2)$ but non of them kills T. Therefore $p(t)$ is the minimal polynomial.

I'm having trouble with this, because I guessed $p(t)$, and Im not sure on how to actually find the polynomial. For example, I have no idea how to find a matrix, because of that transpose. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Does $t$ here mean transpose?  Also, since I saw your earlier edit: $\mathbb{C}$ is given by `\mathbb{C}`.

Comment: Yeah the $t$ power is transpose, and thanks for the tip!

Comment: Your work and deduction are correct...and hopefully you can explain both. Good work. +1

Comment: I guess I should'ent doubt myself that much , thanks a lot!

Comment: You can look at the problem from a different angle. Ask yourself what are the eigenvectors for $T$. If $A$ is symmetric, then $T(A) = 0$. If $A$ is antisymmetric then $T(A) = -2A$. Since every matrix is a sum of its symmetric and antisymmetric part, so $T(T+2)$ kills every matrix and hence $p(t) = t(t+2)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know if i can say anything better than what you have done...

You have seen what $T^2$ would be... this is what you actually have to do..

see what would   $T,T^2,T^3\cdots$ be and check for a liner combination that would result zero map ..

You have seen the very first non trivial power of $T$ namely $T^2$ and realized it as $-2T$

So, You have $T^2=-2T$ and remaining thing i want to say is not any better than yours..

So, What you have done is natural for me..

P.S : All this is just for your statement **I guessed $p(t)$  and I'm not sure on how to actually find the polynomial**

Comment: For some reason I didnt realize that $T^2$ is $-2T$ , seems kind of obvious now. But I understand the process now, thanks!

Comment: you are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Computing powers of $T$ and seeing what happens is a good approach here, because of the simple form that $T$ is given in. Another approach would be to view $T$ as a linear map on $M_n(\Bbb{C})$ given by
$$T:\ M_n(\Bbb{C})\ \longrightarrow\ M_n(\Bbb{C}):\ (a_{ij})_{1\leq i,j\leq n}\ \longmapsto\ (a_{ji}-a_{ij})_{1\leq i,j\leq n},$$
with respect to the natural basis. For all $1\leq i,j\leq n$ the subspaces
$$\operatorname{span}(E_{ii})\qquad\text{ and }\qquad\operatorname{span}(E_{ij}, E_{ji}),$$
are invariant under $T$, so $T$ is represented by a block diagonal matrix, with blocks of the form
$$\begin{pmatrix}0\end{pmatrix}\qquad\text{ and }\qquad\begin{pmatrix}-1&1\\1&-1\end{pmatrix},$$
respectively, and the characteristic polynomial of the latter is
$$\det\left(\begin{pmatrix}-1&1\\1&-1\end{pmatrix}-tI\right)=(-1-t)^2-1^2=t^2+2t$$
Hence this is its minimal polynomial of every $2\times2$-block, and therefore it is also the minimal polynomial of $T$.